# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python, django, mongodb

What could possibly be the reason of this error? I am using a ubuntu guest server in a windows 10 host system

The entire error is as follows:

```
` File "train_data.py", line 36, in <module>
    update_database.insert_features(features)
  File "/pupyl/preprocessing_data/update_database_with_features.py", line 59, in insert_features
    self.db_operation.insert_record(records, "train")
  File "/pupyl/database_client/database_operations.py", line 33, in insert_record
    self.db.train.insert(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 3161, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 607, in _insert
    bypass_doc_val, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 595, in _insert_one
    acknowledged, _insert_command, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1242, in _retryable_write
    with self._tmp_session(session) as s:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1571, in _tmp_session
    s = self._ensure_session(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1558, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1511, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1544, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 427, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
`
```

train_data.py is as follows, if that helps:

```
    features: Tuple[List[str], List[str], List[str], List[bool], List[str]] = \
        extract_features.separation_of_features(parsed_json)

    update_database.insert_features(features)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `train_data.py`?  Looks like something's failing on line 36, but if it's not too much code then consider pasting the whole file.

Comment: @RichieThomas updated the needful line

Answer (score 0):

seems like your application is not being able to connect to database, verify if the database is actually running on localhost:27017 and accepting connections
ps: try connecting with mongoshell